# How to retrieve a value from a column after retrieving one value before

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope you can help me with this one. I know the title is a little bit confusing so let me clarify. Let's say I have a column `"ORDERS"` with rows `"ORDER ID"`, `"ORDER #"`, `"CODE"` and `"DATE"`

Let's say the orders can have plenty of codes in the same order (so this table will be joining another, but is not relevant at the moment) and at any certain time.

If I want to retrieve the ORDER #'s of rows with the same "CODE", and in between this first "CODE", there should not be another "CODE" after 100 hours. But then, I also want the very first "CODE" that may comer after the 100 hours.

I am not looking for an exact answer. I am looking mainly if there are ways of doing this. Can it be done with multiple instances of the table? And how could the logic be implemented?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a sample of what your data looks like to help us better understand what you're asking?

Comment: While I'm not exactly clear what you are asking, perhaps looking into  [FIRST/LAST](http://psoug.org/definition/LAST.htm) would help?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the `lag()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by order#, code order by date) as prevdate
      from t
     ) t
where date - prevdate >= 100/24.0 or prevdate is null;
```

This fetches the previous date for the `order#`, `code` combination.  It then chooses the rows that are more than 100 hours from the previous one with the same `order#` and `code`.